# Custom gate labels in PennyLane

Tags: quantum-circuit, pennylane

I have a circuit with Rx gate, and I want to draw it with changed gate label. For example, instead of "RX" I want to have "custom_gate" written in the gate box.
I have tried following code:

```
op = qml.RX(1.23456, wires=0, id='custom_gate')
op.name = 'custom_gate'
op.label(decimals=None, base_label="custom_gate", cache=None)

def circ():
    qml.apply(op)
    return 0

fig, ax = qml.draw_mpl(circ)()
```

And get this result:

[image]

Also, I've tried doing it with QNode instance, instead of quantum function -- got no difference.

As you can see, I've put "custom_gate" in several places, but none of them seems to work.
Not sure, if I am doing it correctly, so please, show me a way how to do this. Probably, I have to acces the operations in constructed Qnode tape instead of initial gate, but both `tape` and `qtape` are NoneType objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, good news: Your approach to provide an `id` in order to impact the drawn circuit has been implemented [very recently](https://github.com/PennyLaneAI/pennylane/pull/4749). So recent in fact, it is not in the newest release 0.33.1 of PennyLane yet, but will be included in 0.34. In the meantime, you can install from the `master` branch on Github to get the feature right now.

The `id` will yield something like this:

```python
import pennylane as qml

@qml.qnode(qml.device('lightning.qubit', wires=1))
def circuit(a):
    qml.RX(a, wires=0, id="my Op")
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

print(qml.draw(circuit)(a=2.3))

>>> 0: ──RX(2.30,"my Op")─┤  <Z>

fig, ax = qml.draw_mpl(circuit)(a=2.3)
```

[image]

If you are not quite happy with this result (or want to stick to released versions), you can also create a custom operation with the desired name:

```python
import pennylane as qml

class MyOp(qml.RX):
    pass

@qml.qnode(qml.device('lightning.qubit', wires=1))
def circuit(a):
    op = MyOp(a, wires=0)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

print(qml.draw(circuit)(a=2.3))

>>> 0: ──MyOp(2.30)─┤  <Z>

fig, ax = qml.draw_mpl(circuit)(a=2.3)
```

[image]

Finally, if you want a label that is not a valid Python class name, you can get a bit hacky (not recommended, because it may interfere with functionality other than drawing!):

```python
class MyOp(qml.RX):
    pass

MyOp.__name__ = "my OP"

@qml.qnode(qml.device('lightning.qubit', wires=1))
def circuit(a):
    op = MyOp(a, wires=0)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

print(qml.draw(circuit)(a=2.3))

>>> 0: ──my Op(2.30)─┤  <Z>

fig, ax = qml.draw_mpl(circuit)(a=2.3)
plt.savefig("id_label.png")
```

[image]
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted!